# Whitehead manifold is contractible

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, reference-request, manifolds, homotopy-theory

I've been looking for a proof that the Whitehead manifold is contractible. I'm hoping to find something a little easier to read than Whitehead's original paper "A Certain Open Manifold Whose Group is Unity." I would especially like something more geometrically motivated, as opposed to a proof which uses nuclear weapons of algebraic topology. But beggars can't be choosers!

Comment: Perhaps you ought to explain which nuclear weapons you wish to avoid. Just as an example, there's a few nice tools such as the Hurewicz Theorem and Whitehead's Theorem which make the verification very simple. But perhaps you think of those tools as nuclear weapons? If so, then one could perhaps disassemble the nuclear weapons and describe their proofs and applications using only a gigantic boxful of wrenches and screwdrivers and hammers. I'm doubtful of the utility of that process, though.... seems easier to me to just learn the proofs of those theorems.

Comment: In fact, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold) gives an almost complete proof of contractibility. It is complete if you know basic algebraic topology tools such as ones mentioned by Lee Mosher in his comment. Proving that a manifold is contractible without using such tools is, in mind mind, quite pointless.